# MySQL user with ALL PRIVILEGES can login but not run queries

Tags: mysql, permissions, plesk

We've configured our Plesk machine to use an external MySQL server. In doing so, we've granted ALL privileges WITH GRANT OPTION to the psaadmin user so we are able to create remote databases and users just fine. However, the users we create (i.e. 'wordpress_user') cannot run select statements on the remote server.

In checking permissions on the MySQL server, 'wordpress_user' has ALL PRIVILEGES to the database itself. I'm able to login to phpMyAdmin with that user and I'm able to login on the remote server console with that user. It's only when I try to run any query as that user that I get a 'ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user' error.

Everything I've checked seems to indicate the user has full permissions. I've also used FLUSH PRIVILEGES as instructed by the docs. I've restarted Plesk, restarted MySQL, still nothing.

Can anyone help? Please?

Comment: granting permission to access doesn't mean you granted the user the rights to select , update , delete ,etc to the user. May I know the query you used for granting permission

Comment: Try deleting the user and re-create that user or a new one. Go through and assign all the necessary access privileges. You probably missed/overlooked something. MySQL is pretty straight forward. :-) Good Luck.

Comment: Check you have created user with localhost or % or specific ip. Check user table of mysql database

Comment: The user had ALL PRIVILEGES, not just ACCESS.

Comment: I was able to find the problem. Apparently the problematic query was a view that had specific permissions? Regular selects, etc. worked fine (I didn't realize that). I was able to drop and recreate the view and it works great now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find the problem. Apparently the problematic query was a view that had specific permissions? Regular selects, etc. worked fine (I didn't realize that). I was able to drop and recreate the view and it works great now.